# What is the purpose of Ember.Deferred?

Tags: ember.js

I'm finding it awfully difficult to come across anything about `Ember.Deferred`. I've looked through the source code of EmberJS, and so I understand its methods. I've also discovered it relates to the promise pattern. However, any further information about this recently added mixin would be more than appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Ember.Deferred is [RSVP.js](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js) in the form of an Ember.Mixin.

RSVP.js is an implementation of [Promises/A](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A).

Answer (score 3):

A part of the gameplan for Ember.Deferred is to use it in Ember Data, so that models and queries become promises that resolve when they load. You can start using it now anywhere you might want to use the Promises/A pattern. If you don't use or understand that pattern, you can safely ignore Ember.Deferred for the time being.